# Excel vba defined footer

Tags: vba, excel, date

The folowing code is used to auto define the header/footer while plotting an excel worksheet to pdf.
Only thing that doesn't seem to work is the centerfooter function, it's supposed to give "*active sheet name* - *defined date in dd-mm-yyyy format (value of cell Sheets("instellingen").Cells(22, 2) )*, this results only in returning the date in format "mm-dd-yyyy" in the centerfooter, ignoring and not returning the activesheet name part.

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = "Company name"
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = Sheets("instellingen").Cells(20, 2).Value
        .CenterFooter = Activesheet.name & " - " & Sheets("instellingen").Cells(22, 2).Value
        .RightFooter = "Pagina &P van de &N"
```

Thanks :)

*Edit. (full macro)*

```
Sub PlotPDF()
'
' PlotPDF Macro
'
' Sneltoets: Ctrl+Shift+P
'
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A:$N"
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = "Company name"
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = Sheets("instellingen").Cells(20, 2).Value
        .CenterFooter = ActiveSheet.Name & " - " & Format(Sheets("instellingen").Cells(22, 2).Value, "dd-MM-yyyy")
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you got any Error handling in your code which may be causing to skip over this? Something like `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: Works for me as well. I get the activesheet name and the time, separated by a slash.

Comment: Can you put a MsgBox here `MsgBox (Activesheet.name & " - " & Sheets("instellingen").Cells(22, 2).Value)`?

Comment: the msgbox works, but when plotting it still only returns the date, I've put the whole macro in the question above, maybe I'm missing something else?

Comment: if i put an enter in between, it does work
`ActiveSheet.Name & Chr(10) & Format(Sheets("instellingen").Cells(22, 2).Value, "dd-MM-yyyy")`
Don't know what makes the difference though :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Format() function to format the date in .Cell(22, 2)

```
.CenterFooter = ActiveSheet.Name & " - " & Format(Sheets("instellingen").Cells(22, 2).Value, "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Comment: It's the `ActiveSheet.Name` that is missing not the Date